# Define a random 3-D array x2 of shape (x, y, z) and of numbers between 0 and 1

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, random, numpy-ndarray

Note: Set numpy random seed value 100

• Define a random 3-D array x2 of shape (x, y, z) and of numbers between 0 and 1

• Print the value of x2

✓ Sample Case

Sample Input

3 4 2

Sample Output

[[[0.00568851 0.25242635]....

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is always great to show what efforts you have been already done to solve this problem, how far you've got.

If the distribution is uniform, I'd use a code like this:

```py
import sys
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(100)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x, y, z = [int(val) for val in sys.argv[1:4]]
    rnd_mat = numpy.random.uniform(low=0, high=1, size=(x, y, z))
    print(rnd_mat)
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the question I was attempting today & I've made it to the answer

```
import numpy as np
import random

a = np.random.uniform(0,1,x*y*z)
print(x)
x1 = a.reshape(x,y,z)
x1
```

This answers your question.

[image: Define a random 3-D array x2 of shape (x, y, z) and of numbers between 0 and 1]

The question is just the second part of this entire question in HackerRank. You can visit the question [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/test/fds1n0bsdlp/questions/d1nmj6ea6fr).